SNMPv3 Trap Receiver
I'm currently working on configuring a SNMPv3 trap receiver using Python. Below are the relevant configuration files and Python script:
#
# EXAMPLE-trap.conf:
#   An example configuration file for configuring the Net-SNMP snmptrapd agent.
#
###############################################################################
#
# This file is intended to only be an example.
# When the snmptrapd agent starts up, this is where it will look for it.
#
# All lines beginning with a '#' are comments and are intended for you
# to read.  All other lines are configuration commands for the agent.

#
# PLEASE: read the snmptrapd.conf(5) manual page as well!
#
# Create SNMPv3 user
createUser -e 0x5072697374696E65 rberbato SHA "AuthPass" AES "EncPass"
snmpTrapdAddr udp:0.0.0.0:1162,udp6:[::]:1162
authUser log,execute,net rberbato
authCommunity log,execute,net PUBLIC　
#authCommunity log,execute,net public
#
## send mail when get any events
traphandle default /home/rberbato/Pristine/receiveSNMPTraps.py
#traphandle default /home/rberbato/Pristine/receiveSNMPTrapsv3.py
#
## send mail when get linkDown
#traphandle .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3 /usr/bin/traptoemail -s smtp.example.org foobar@example.org
#doNotLogTraps yes
#doNotFork yes     
#disableAuthorization yes  

receiveSNMPTraps.py:
# Python SNMP trap receiver
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import ntfrcv
import logging

snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()

user = 'rberbato'
AuthPass = 'AuthPass'
EncPass = 'EncPass'
TrapAgentAddress='0.0.0.0';  # Trap listener address
Port=162;  # Trap listener port

logging.basicConfig(filename='received_traps.log', filemode='w', format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

logging.info("Agent is listening SNMP Trap on "+TrapAgentAddress+" , Port : " +str(Port))
logging.info('--------------------------------------------------------------------------')

print("Agent is listening SNMP Trap on "+TrapAgentAddress+" , Port : " +str(Port))

config.addTransport(
    snmpEngine,
    udp.domainName + (1,),
    udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode((TrapAgentAddress, Port))
)

# Configure community here
config.addV1System(snmpEngine, 'PUBLIC', 'PUBLIC')

# Configure SNMPv3 user
config.addV3User(
    snmpEngine, user, config.usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol,
    AuthPass, config.usmAesCfb128Protocol, EncPass,
)

def cbFun(snmpEngine, stateReference, contextEngineId, contextName,
          varBinds, cbCtx):
    print("Received new Trap message")
    logging.info("Received new Trap message")
    for name, val in varBinds:   
        logging.info('%s = %s' % (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))
        print('%s = %s' % (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))

    logging.info("==== End of Incoming Trap ====")
ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(snmpEngine, cbFun)

snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)  

try:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
except:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
    raise

I can successfully receive SNMPv1 traps, but SNMPv3 traps are not being processed. The receiveSNMPTraps.py script receives SNMPv3 traps but does not process them.
I've tried changing encryption and authentication passphrases and protocols, as well as including Engine ID and context, but I still encounter this issue.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This is my SNMP output in my virtual CSR1kv router:
User name: rberbato
Engine ID: 5072697374696E65
storage-type: nonvolatile        active
Authentication Protocol: SHA
Privacy Protocol: AES128
Group-name: admin

DNDEN0002P#show snmp context
Pristine


That’s well known. Your trap listener must trust the sender by knowing its credentials and remote engine ID. You didn’t do that yet.

More information for your reference, https://github.com/lextudio/pysnmp/blob/main/tests/manager_context.py

Thank you @Lex,
I tried adding the engine ID but still not working.
Do you have any idea how should I defined context name in snmptrapd.conf or in python script?

I tried sending an SNMPv3 trap without context name and it's working properly
